# Subset tibble of four specific rows

Tags: r, select, subset

I have a tibble, named Alabama, with 31 rows and I want a new tibble made of only rows 1, 11, 21, 31. These rows have are in a column named Year and have the values 1970, 1980, 1990, 2000

I have tried

```
al_decades <- filter(Alabama, Year==1970 && Year==1980 && Year==1990 && Year==2000)
```

and

```
al_decades <- subset(Alabama, Year==1970 && Year==1980 && Year==1990 && Year==2000)
```

but neither has worked.

Comment: A single year can't be both equal to 1970 and 1980 at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need `%in%` instead of `==`

```
library(dplyr)
new <- filter(Alabama, Year %in% c(1970, 1980, 1990, 2000))
```

Or instead of `&` (not `&&`), use `|` to check for multiple elements as 'Year' wouldn't have different years in the same row

```
new <- filter(Alabama, (Year == 1970)|(Year == 1980)|(Year == 1990)|(Year == 2000))
```

Or if we are only interested in the decades, then another option is

```
new <- filter(Alabama, Year %%10 == 0)
```

---

If we know the position, another option is `slice`

```
new <- Alabama %>%
          slice(c(1, 11, 21, 31))
```

Or use `filter` with `row_number()`

```
new <- Alabama %>%
           filter(row_number() %in% c(1, 11, 21, 31))
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Alabama, key = 'Year')[J(c(1970, 1980, 1990, 2000))]
```

---

In `base R`, we can use `subset`

```
subset(Alabama, Year %in% c(1970, 1980, 1990, 2000))
```

Comment: this was such a thorough and well stated answer, thank you very much!